# spring Kafka listening to regex

Tags: java, spring, spring-kafka

I am trying to listen newly created topic with the below code, but is not working. Can you please tell me if the below code is correct?

```
public class KafkaMessageListener {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaMessageListener.class);

    private final ProcessEventModel eventModel;

    @KafkaListener(topicPattern = "betsyncDataTopic*")
    public void receive(ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord) {
        LOGGER.info("received payload at '{}'", consumerRecord.timestamp());
        eventModel.process(consumerRecord.value());
    }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your regex is not valid; it should be `betsyncDataTopic.*`.

```
@KafkaListener(id = "xxx", topicPattern = "kbgh.*")
public void listen(String in) {
    System.out.println(in);
}
```

...

```
partitions assigned: [kbgh290-0]
```

**EDIT**

If you later add new topics that match the pattern, there will be a delay before the rebalance. According to the `KafkaConsumer` javadocs...

```
 * Subscribe to all topics matching specified pattern to get dynamically assigned partitions.
 * The pattern matching will be done periodically against topic existing at the time of check.
 * <p>
 * As part of group management, the consumer will keep track of the list of consumers that
 * belong to a particular group and will trigger a rebalance operation if one of the
 * following events trigger -
 * <ul>
 * <li>Number of partitions change for any of the subscribed list of topics
 * <li>Topic is created or deleted
 * <li>An existing member of the consumer group dies
 * <li>A new member is added to an existing consumer group via the join API
 * </ul>
```

I just ran a test; added a new matching topic at `12:13:32`; result:

```
2018-02-12 12:17:30.394  INFO 88028 --- [      xxx-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    
: partitions revoked: [kbgh290-0]
2018-02-12 12:17:30.450  INFO 88028 --- [      xxx-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    
: partitions assigned: [kbgh290-0, kbghNew-0]
```

So it takes 5 minutes, by default.

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_metadata.max.age.ms

> The period of time in milliseconds after which we force a refresh of metadata even if we haven't seen any partition leadership changes to proactively discover any new brokers or partitions.

Comment: Hi @Gary, it worked but not picking the message from the dynamically created topic. Do you think there is a way to get those message from newly created topic "kbgh.1234"?

Comment: Thanks, Gary, I saw it. Initially, I had 1000 topics, and then I added few hundred more, so there was a long delay, but when I have 40-50 topics and I increased by 10-15, it was quicker.

Comment: The default metadata refresh time is 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

topicPattern should be **betsyncDataTopic.***

when topic is created, consumer have to wait to refresh with new metadata. it takes 5 minutes because of metadata.max.age.ms default value:  https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs_metadata.max.age.ms